# Spotipy API Not Returning Using Client Credentials

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy

I am trying to return a list of tracks from public playlists using spotipy in python. At first it was working, then stopped. I have my CID and Client Secret, which hasn't changed. When trying to switch to the token authentication way, I get an HTTP error "returned 400 due to Only valid bearer authentication supported". When running with client credentials I get no response at all.

```
# Authentication without user 
client_credentials_manage = SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id=cid, client_secret-secret, requests_session=True)
# cache_token = client_credentials_manage.get_access_token(cid) 
sp = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=client_credentials_manage)
```

Where I am trying to get playlist tracks:

```
try: 
    print('getting in here') 
    response = sp.playlist_tracks (link) 
    track_items =response['items']
```

[Client Credentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onDdx.png)
[What I am trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaPvt.png)

I think there is something wrong with the way I am doing the client credentials.

Comment: Please read the following page, and improve your question (I didn't actually downvote): https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Please don't upload images of stacktraces or code, format them into the question

Comment: @c.Nivs sorry I tried to add them into the question but this is my first post so I couldn't figure it out

Answer (score 0):

##### You need to change it

From

```
response = sp.playlist_tracks (link)
```

To

```
response = sp.playlist_tracks (playlist_id = '<play list id string>')
```

##### Spotipy function parameter helping in VS code

How do I know?, If the mouse hover on API (ex `playlist_track`) after `pip install spotipy`

The pop-up suggestion for function arguments in VS code. like this.
I can see the `playlist_id` is one of parameter, there are no list parameter.

[image]

Or if CTRL + click on API, VS code open the function's arguments list.
It is same as pop-up.

[image]

So this demo code is to get public playlist songs.

##### Demo code

```py
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials
import json

CLIENT_ID = "<your Client ID>"
CLIENT_SECRET = "<your Client Secret>"

# https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.22.1/?highlight=SpotifyClientCredentials#client-credentials-flow
auth_manager = SpotifyClientCredentials(
    client_id=CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET,
    requests_session=True)

def get_songs(playlist_id):
    try:
        sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=auth_manager)
        songs = []

        # Spotipy API call in https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.22.1/?highlight=playlist_tracks#spotipy.client.Spotify.playlist_tracks
        results = sp.playlist_tracks(playlist_id = playlist_id)

        # loop for adding song by list append
        for item in results['items']:
            if (item is not None and item['track'] is not None and item['track']['id'] is not None and item['track']['name'] is not None and item['track']['external_urls']['spotify'] is not None):
                songs.append({
                    'id' : item['track']['id'],
                    'title': item['track']['name'],
                    'artist_name': item['track']['artists'][0]['name'],
                    'album_name': item['track']['album']['name'],
                    'release_date': item['track']['album']['release_date'],
                    'total_tracks': item['track']['album']['total_tracks'],
                    'url': item['track']['external_urls']['spotify']
                })
            else:
                break
        return songs
    except Exception as e:
        print('Failed to upload to call get_songs: '+ str(e))

# Get public playlist songs
songs = get_songs('37i9dQZF1DX0tnKPLNG9Ld')

# DIsplay Terminal
print(json.dumps(songs, indent = 4))

# Writing json file
with open('songs.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(songs, fp, indent = 4)
```

This is demo of public playlist.

```
https://open.spotify.com/playlist/37i9dQZF1DX0tnKPLNG9Ld
```

[image]

##### Result saved JSON file

```
[
    {
        "id": "5cdBPBfYeRFDZWHAk4UPOH",
        "title": "Blue Skies",
        "artist_name": "Frank Sinatra",
        "album_name": "The Essential Frank Sinatra",
        "release_date": "2010-10-26",
        "total_tracks": 36,
        "url": "https://open.spotify.com/track/5cdBPBfYeRFDZWHAk4UPOH"
    },
    {
        "id": "5y8zb3grlQonjdqd27K39T",
        "title": "A Kiss To Build A Dream On - Single Version",
        "artist_name": "Louis Armstrong",
        "album_name": "Satchmo Serenades",
        "release_date": "1952-04-01",
        "total_tracks": 18,
        "url": "https://open.spotify.com/track/5y8zb3grlQonjdqd27K39T"
    },
    {
        "id": "1oDCK7PW72XEZ1pE5rh87A",
        "title": "Smile",
        "artist_name": "Nat King Cole",
        "album_name": "The Nat King Cole Story",
        "release_date": "1991-01-01",
        "total_tracks": 36,
        "url": "https://open.spotify.com/track/1oDCK7PW72XEZ1pE5rh87A"
    },
    {
        "id": "0Juciz8gOjrO89qw5KwQV5",
        "title": "Call Me Irresponsible - 2001 Remaster",
        "artist_name": "Bobby Darin",
        "album_name": "From Hello Dolly To Goodbye Charlie",
        "release_date": "1964-01-01",
        "total_tracks": 11,
        "url": "https://open.spotify.com/track/0Juciz8gOjrO89qw5KwQV5"
    },
    {
        "id": "6qMMQzYTKabamnMPlCmfxb",
        "title": "On The Street Where You Live - 1998 Remaster",
        "artist_name": "Dean Martin",
        "album_name": "This Time I'm Swingin'",
        "release_date": "1960",
        "total_tracks": 12,
        "url": "https://open.spotify.com/track/6qMMQzYTKabamnMPlCmfxb"
    },
    {
        "id": "0CczH75yFBo53bVqLRvYn4",
        "title": "Till There Was You - Remastered",
        "artist_name": "Peggy Lee",
        "album_name": "Latin Ala Lee",
        "release_date": "1960-01-04",
        "total_tracks": 12,
        "url": "https://open.spotify.com/track/0CczH75yFBo53bVqLRvYn4"
    },
    {
        "id": "1eWgwHZXvYG6Odpx7QwJmT",
        "title": "These Are The Days",
        "artist_name": "Jamie Cullum",
        "album_name": "Twentysomething",
        "release_date": "2003-10-20",
        "total_tracks": 19,
        "url": "https://open.spotify.com/track/1eWgwHZXvYG6Odpx7QwJmT"
    },
    {
        "id": "5b7OgznPJJr1vHNYGyvxau",
        "title": "Fly Me To The Moon (In Other Words)",
        "artist_name": "Frank Sinatra",
        "album_name": "Sinatra/Basie: The Complete Reprise Studio Recordings",
        "release_date": "1962-12-10",
        "total_tracks": 20,
        "url": "https://open.spotify.com/track/5b7OgznPJJr1vHNYGyvxau"
    },
    {
        "id": "16ARXAJAcL8ubHDpBLcqDQ",
        "title": "On The Sunny Side Of The Street",
        "artist_name": "Billie Holiday",
        "album_name": "Billie Holiday",
        "release_date": "1957-01-01",
        "total_tracks": 12,
        "url": "https://open.spotify.com/track/16ARXAJAcL8ubHDpBLcqDQ"
    },
    {
        "id": "7GBPpRMtLyGA6svXQMNfIN",
        "title": "Bye Bye Blackbird",
        "artist_name": "Etta Jones",
        "album_name": "Don't Go To Strangers (Rudy Van Gelder Remaster)",
        "release_date": "1960-01-01",
        "total_tracks": 10,
        "url": "https://open.spotify.com/track/7GBPpRMtLyGA6svXQMNfIN"
    },
    {
        "id": "4MVvSNPOUd2z70vkkNCbLr",
        "title": "The Good Life",
        "artist_name": "Tony Bennett",
        "album_name": "I Wanna Be Around",
        "release_date": "1963-02-18",
        "total_tracks": 18,
        "url": "https://open.spotify.com/track/4MVvSNPOUd2z70vkkNCbLr"
    },
    {
        "id": "0YUsHYHiwi6drC1ATz47hm",
        "title": "Let's Do It (Let's Fall In Love)",
        "artist_name": "Ella Fitzgerald",
        "album_name": "Someone To Watch Over Me",
        "release_date": "2017-09-29",
        "total_tracks": 12,
        "url": "https://open.spotify.com/track/0YUsHYHiwi6drC1ATz47hm"
    },
    {
        "id": "2chTka18XL8un05Pkb8Lis",
        "title": "The Boy From Ipanema",
        "artist_name": "Nancy Wilson",
        "album_name": "How Glad I Am",
        "release_date": "1964-01-01",
        "total_tracks": 10,
        "url": "https://open.spotify.com/track/2chTka18XL8un05Pkb8Lis"
    },
    {
        "id": "4QJ1F5dFjDTnoHgew9cdRr",
        "title": "Sweet Happy Life",
        "artist_name": "Peggy Lee",
        "album_name": "Guitars A La Lee",
        "release_date": "1966-10-01",
        "total_tracks": 12,
        "url": "https://open.spotify.com/track/4QJ1F5dFjDTnoHgew9cdRr"
    },
    {
        "id": "5XrLzC6tClHbANUOmPYg2E",
        "title": "Days Of Wine And Roses",
        "artist_name": "Frank Sinatra",
        "album_name": "Days Of Wine And Roses, Moon River And Other Academy Award Winners",
        "release_date": "1964",
        "total_tracks": 11,
        "url": "https://open.spotify.com/track/5XrLzC6tClHbANUOmPYg2E"
    },
    {
        "id": "0ApUPYg8ifMJZchhFeFLDs",
        "title": "It's A Lovely Day Today",
        "artist_name": "Perry Como",
        "album_name": "Perry Como with the Fontane Sisters (with The Fontane Sisters)",
        "release_date": "2001-08-06",
        "total_tracks": 14,
        "url": "https://open.spotify.com/track/0ApUPYg8ifMJZchhFeFLDs"
    },
    {
        "id": "3qTYzMkbzxqRtA2hlSz4Ba",
        "title": "It Had to Be You",
        "artist_name": "Bobby Darin",
        "album_name": "Love Swings",
        "release_date": "1961",
        "total_tracks": 12,
        "url": "https://open.spotify.com/track/3qTYzMkbzxqRtA2hlSz4Ba"
    },
    {
        "id": "19qklMrfkSQjwIR33bAIN7",
        "title": "Give Me The Simple Life",
        "artist_name": "June Christy",
        "album_name": "Gone For The Day",
        "release_date": "1957-10-09",
        "total_tracks": 12,
        "url": "https://open.spotify.com/track/19qklMrfkSQjwIR33bAIN7"
    },
    {
        "id": "04kFa5D5by0or1IN6bI9N7",
        "title": "I Could Write A Book",
        "artist_name": "Anita O'Day",
        "album_name": "Swings Rodgers And Hart",
        "release_date": "1960-01-01",
        "total_tracks": 12,
        "url": "https://open.spotify.com/track/04kFa5D5by0or1IN6bI9N7"
    },
    {
        "id": "4i3Js0sRUEfBSvIwCPvKRz",
        "title": "The More I See You",
        "artist_name": "Chet Baker",
        "album_name": "Chet Baker Sings: It Could Happen To You [Original Jazz Classics Remasters] (OJC Remaster)",
        "release_date": "2010-01-01",
        "total_tracks": 14,
        "url": "https://open.spotify.com/track/4i3Js0sRUEfBSvIwCPvKRz"
    },
    {
        "id": "5qWXXF3On2xUfVu1ND1NLN",
        "title": "Cheek to Cheek",
        "artist_name": "Fred Astaire",
        "album_name": "The Essential Fred Astaire",
        "release_date": "1935",
        "total_tracks": 15,
        "url": "https://open.spotify.com/track/5qWXXF3On2xUfVu1ND1NLN"
    },
    {
        "id": "3XOJhbofb4qTZdt0RLLrUq",
        "title": "All Of You",
        "artist_name": "Billie Holiday",
        "album_name": "Billie Holiday With Ray Ellis And His Orchestra",
        "release_date": "1959-07-01",
        "total_tracks": 12,
        "url": "https://open.spotify.com/track/3XOJhbofb4qTZdt0RLLrUq"
    },
    {
        "id": "0vFP6jMvrIsmxdwVdza7GA",
        "title": "Make Someone Happy - From \"Do Re Mi\"",
        "artist_name": "Margaret Whiting",
        "album_name": "Broadway, Right Now!",
        "release_date": "1961-09-23",
        "total_tracks": 12,
        "url": "https://open.spotify.com/track/0vFP6jMvrIsmxdwVdza7GA"
    },
    {
        "id": "6ghdeAG64RBwahVxWzj9sa",
        "title": "C'est Magnifique - Remastered",
        "artist_name": "Kay Starr",
        "album_name": "Movin' On Broadway",
        "release_date": "2011-01-01",
        "total_tracks": 12,
        "url": "https://open.spotify.com/track/6ghdeAG64RBwahVxWzj9sa"
    },
    {
        "id": "0qZo9OzKPzg58Ts9ad4Bcy",
        "title": "All Of Me",
        "artist_name": "Ella Fitzgerald",
        "album_name": "Ella Swings Gently With Nelson",
        "release_date": "1962-01-21",
        "total_tracks": 15,
        "url": "https://open.spotify.com/track/0qZo9OzKPzg58Ts9ad4Bcy"
    },
    {
        "id": "5kapVb34raTBsynt0Zj6qw",
        "title": "Bossa Antigua",
        "artist_name": "Paul Desmond",
        "album_name": "Bossa Antigua",
        "release_date": "1997",
        "total_tracks": 11,
        "url": "https://open.spotify.com/track/5kapVb34raTBsynt0Zj6qw"
    },
    {
        "id": "6TSeKvWgaYitBKSanHfWsy",
        "title": "Cheek To Cheek",
        "artist_name": "Sammy Davis Jr.",
        "album_name": "Boy Meets Girl: Sammy Davis Jr. And Carmen McRae On Decca",
        "release_date": "1957-01-01",
        "total_tracks": 13,
        "url": "https://open.spotify.com/track/6TSeKvWgaYitBKSanHfWsy"
    },
    {
        "id": "3lXgCSYCH9wCTHHLnpBzig",
        "title": "Beautiful Love",
        "artist_name": "Anita O'Day",
        "album_name": "Anita",
        "release_date": "1955-01-01",
        "total_tracks": 12,
        "url": "https://open.spotify.com/track/3lXgCSYCH9wCTHHLnpBzig"
    },
    {
        "id": "56IPhyZ2ByxWPksbqKpNxF",
        "title": "It Might as Well Be Spring",
        "artist_name": "Caity Gyorgy",
        "album_name": "It Might as Well Be Spring",
        "release_date": "2022-04-08",
        "total_tracks": 1,
        "url": "https://open.spotify.com/track/56IPhyZ2ByxWPksbqKpNxF"
    },
    {
        "id": "77fsTNViSLqcwuSMQhSwB0",
        "title": "As Long As I'm In Your Arms",
        "artist_name": "Dinah Washington",
        "album_name": "September In The Rain",
        "release_date": "1961-01-01",
        "total_tracks": 12,
        "url": "https://open.spotify.com/track/77fsTNViSLqcwuSMQhSwB0"
    },
    {
        "id": "5wK0I2nGDosuttrhkVHZnO",
        "title": "You Couldn't Be Cuter",
        "artist_name": "Margaret Whiting",
        "album_name": "Sings The Jerome Kern Song Book, Vol.1 & 2",
        "release_date": "1960-01-01",
        "total_tracks": 24,
        "url": "https://open.spotify.com/track/5wK0I2nGDosuttrhkVHZnO"
    },
    {
        "id": "5935p4F2K5crvwdc6mBLPg",
        "title": "A-Tisket, A-Tasket",
        "artist_name": "Ella Fitzgerald",
        "album_name": "Get Happy! (Expanded Edition)",
        "release_date": "1959-01-01",
        "total_tracks": 14,
        "url": "https://open.spotify.com/track/5935p4F2K5crvwdc6mBLPg"
    },
    {
        "id": "08RnPHoZRQr6BuD92JRvkk",
        "title": "You Make Me Feel so Young",
        "artist_name": "Rosemary Clooney",
        "album_name": "The Essential Rosemary Clooney",
        "release_date": "1948",
        "total_tracks": 16,
        "url": "https://open.spotify.com/track/08RnPHoZRQr6BuD92JRvkk"
    },
    {
        "id": "024nBbxvX3NpCbrw5XZW3B",
        "title": "Alright, Okay, You Win",
        "artist_name": "Count Basie",
        "album_name": "Count Basie Swings - Joe Williams Sings",
        "release_date": "1993-01-01",
        "total_tracks": 12,
        "url": "https://open.spotify.com/track/024nBbxvX3NpCbrw5XZW3B"
    },
    {
        "id": "0KDn1UsD2ym34dCT4P9ebj",
        "title": "What A Little Moonlight Can Do - Remastered",
        "artist_name": "Nancy Wilson",
        "album_name": "Something Wonderful",
        "release_date": "2004-01-01",
        "total_tracks": 12,
        "url": "https://open.spotify.com/track/0KDn1UsD2ym34dCT4P9ebj"
    },
    {
        "id": "2XOXYNVmg0Mpm6WlLC0LHx",
        "title": "Too Marvelous For Words",
        "artist_name": "Billie Holiday",
        "album_name": "Lady Sings The Blues",
        "release_date": "1956-01-01",
        "total_tracks": 12,
        "url": "https://open.spotify.com/track/2XOXYNVmg0Mpm6WlLC0LHx"
    },
    {
        "id": "1kKf0BRGJhPTndA4hkGOAj",
        "title": "Something Happens To Me",
        "artist_name": "Blossom Dearie",
        "album_name": "May I Come In?",
        "release_date": "1964-05-04",
        "total_tracks": 12,
        "url": "https://open.spotify.com/track/1kKf0BRGJhPTndA4hkGOAj"
    },
    {
        "id": "6gaYlANvT72vnO0cGACx2A",
        "title": "Taking A Chance On Love",
        "artist_name": "Anita O'Day",
        "album_name": "Anita Sings The Most",
        "release_date": "1957-01-01",
        "total_tracks": 11,
        "url": "https://open.spotify.com/track/6gaYlANvT72vnO0cGACx2A"
    },
    {
        "id": "2nik1V49EZiLQd2XkTpR2T",
        "title": "I Get A Kick Out Of You",
        "artist_name": "Dinah Washington",
        "album_name": "For Those In Love (Expanded Edition)",
        "release_date": "1955-01-01",
        "total_tracks": 10,
        "url": "https://open.spotify.com/track/2nik1V49EZiLQd2XkTpR2T"
    },
    {
        "id": "5WTduEM9fllIf3eBmfGuOX",
        "title": "Sunny",
        "artist_name": "Morgana King",
        "album_name": "Gemini Changes",
        "release_date": "1967",
        "total_tracks": 12,
        "url": "https://open.spotify.com/track/5WTduEM9fllIf3eBmfGuOX"
    },
    {
        "id": "7viOK0TULHr1y8RU1K0R0s",
        "title": "It's A Big Wide Wonderful World",
        "artist_name": "Betty Carter",
        "album_name": "Inside Betty Carter",
        "release_date": "1993-08-02",
        "total_tracks": 15,
        "url": "https://open.spotify.com/track/7viOK0TULHr1y8RU1K0R0s"
    },
    {
        "id": "2QgtqdIQJTNhStSWal6ceV",
        "title": "Oh! Look At Me Now",
        "artist_name": "Nancy Wilson",
        "album_name": "But Beautiful",
        "release_date": "1969",
        "total_tracks": 13,
        "url": "https://open.spotify.com/track/2QgtqdIQJTNhStSWal6ceV"
    },
    {
        "id": "48SsJI70wRwQkndkebmLAd",
        "title": "(How Little It Matters) How Little We Know",
        "artist_name": "Chris Connor",
        "album_name": "Witchcraft",
        "release_date": "2005-05-17",
        "total_tracks": 12,
        "url": "https://open.spotify.com/track/48SsJI70wRwQkndkebmLAd"
    },
    {
        "id": "1RLrKHljWXVJ8cWQKd0zHn",
        "title": "You're The Top",
        "artist_name": "Anita O'Day",
        "album_name": "Anita",
        "release_date": "1955-01-01",
        "total_tracks": 12,
        "url": "https://open.spotify.com/track/1RLrKHljWXVJ8cWQKd0zHn"
    },
    {
        "id": "2ijBcYi7FZXt7bvuVb7NQz",
        "title": "'S Wonderful",
        "artist_name": "Fred Astaire",
        "album_name": "Mr. Top Hat",
        "release_date": "1957-02-01",
        "total_tracks": 15,
        "url": "https://open.spotify.com/track/2ijBcYi7FZXt7bvuVb7NQz"
    },
    {
        "id": "2bKQdj9DjUQT9q8OvTgCM2",
        "title": "Wandering - Remastered",
        "artist_name": "Oscar Peterson",
        "album_name": "Motions & Emotions",
        "release_date": "2014-01-31",
        "total_tracks": 10,
        "url": "https://open.spotify.com/track/2bKQdj9DjUQT9q8OvTgCM2"
    },
    {
        "id": "4TktGfWqFoYgimmSo1ApQQ",
        "title": "Just You, Just Me - Remastered 1999",
        "artist_name": "Nat King Cole",
        "album_name": "After Midnight: The Complete Session",
        "release_date": "1957-01-07",
        "total_tracks": 18,
        "url": "https://open.spotify.com/track/4TktGfWqFoYgimmSo1ApQQ"
    },
    {
        "id": "1jWOaHSKT7CUcBuLdIcOTp",
        "title": "Cannonball",
        "artist_name": "Cannonball Adderley",
        "album_name": "Julian \"Cannonball\" Adderley",
        "release_date": "1955-01-01",
        "total_tracks": 10,
        "url": "https://open.spotify.com/track/1jWOaHSKT7CUcBuLdIcOTp"
    },
    ...
    {
        "id": "0ajHKnwJuMptJqbhtxSuxU",
        "title": "Farmer's Market",
        "artist_name": "Annie Ross",
        "album_name": "Improvisations for the Human Voice",
        "release_date": "2009",
        "total_tracks": 25,
        "url": "https://open.spotify.com/track/0ajHKnwJuMptJqbhtxSuxU"
    }
]
```